# Centering own created div class responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center my `<div class="loginfeld">` but I cant get it to go center (in the middle), while staying responsive.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class ="loginfeld"> 
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="jumbotron">

                    <center><h1>Hallo!</h1></center>
                    <br>

                    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="benutzername"
                    placeholder="Benutzernamen eingeben">

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="passwort"
                    placeholder="Passwort eingeben">

                    </div>

                    <button type="text" class="btn
                    btn-primary form-control" name ="login">Login</button>
                    <center><p><?php echo $hinweis; ?></p></center>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>    
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my css-style file:

```
.loginfeld{
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 750px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

It does go in the middle of my screen, but it's not really resposive. I tried to use codes which were written in the forum to responsively center it, but it did not work out for me.

Thats how it looks now, after I used the code K_LUN wrote down. It is centerd, but now the login box is messed up.
[image: Thats how it looks now, after I used the code K_LUN wrote down. It is centerd, but now the login box is messed up.]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with those style values. Bootstrap's grid is already centered. You should be styling content _inside_ it, not outside.

Comment: do you mean I should style my <div class="jumbotron"> then?

Comment: I don't like to style _any_ of the elements Bootstrap provides, except using other Bootstrap classes. It's usually not necessary and makes maintenance and further development difficult. Style whats's _inside_ Bootstrap's elements--your elements only. If you explain better what you're trying to do I'm sure we can provide a clean, simple solution.

Comment: To clarify, explain in your post _what_ you're trying to center. Chances are, a standard column and `text-center` will do the job effortlessly.

Comment: I just want that my complete login box is centered right in the middle of the screen and be responsive. So if I would smaller the window, it would stay in the middle.

Comment: If you're asking for _vertical_ centering, you've done a poor job of saying so. I just now realized that that's what you might be after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provides more than enough classes to achieve what you need with *minimal* custom CSS.

I deleted the additional `col-lg-4` that you had at the start and end of the container; also added a `row` div since you should have `col-*` classes inside a row only.

After that, you can just add `justify-content-center` to the row to center the element, as well as `align-items-center` along with a custom property `height: 100vh` so the row uses the full height of the viewport.

```css
.full-scrn {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center full-scrn">
      <div class="col-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
        <div class="jumbotron">

          <center>
            <h1>Hallo!</h1>
          </center>
          <br>

          <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="benutzername" placeholder="Benutzernamen eingeben">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort eingeben">

            </div>

            <button type="text" class="btn
                    btn-primary form-control" name="login">Login</button>
            <center>
              <p>
                <?php echo $hinweis; ?>
              </p>
            </center>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. So the best approach is to use the tools Boostrap is offering and just adjust it with some css.

Comment: Yes, but first check if Bootstrap doesn't have a class for what you need to do already; if it doesn't , then you should create *your own* class and add the properties to it... You *should not* modify Bootstrap classes directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid offsets to keep a column centered:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="text-center">Hallo!</h1>

      <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="benutzername" placeholder="Benutzernamen eingeben">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="passwort" placeholder="Passwort eingeben">

        </div>

        <button type="text" class="btn
                    btn-primary form-control" name="login">Login</button>
          <p class="text-center">
            <?php echo $hinweis; ?>
          </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/98avdx2n/)**

Notice a few things:

- Use `text-center` rather than additional markup for centering
- Don't use line breaks for spacing. Use CSS (`.jumbotron h1 {margin-bottom: 20px;}`)

Comment: u can able to adjust `<div>` position  with changing `offset-md-3 or other`

Comment: After I used that, it just moved the login box a little bit more to the right :/

Comment: Based on the updates to your question, this is probably the right approach. You size the column as needed for your content and offset half the column balance. Hint: use even number column sizes so the balance is even as well.

Comment: kealaxshan, pardon my heavy edit. I thought a more complete demo might be appreciated.

Comment: I would say that `offset` is not the best way, since you have to account for different offsets depending on the screen size; instead using flex utilities classes would be better to justify and align content regardless of the screen size

Comment: First of all, thank you all for contributing and helping me! I used the code above and it moved my loginbox just a little more to the right, just like in the code Dev.Mehul wrote down. But I used the boostrap method and just adjusted the width with css. I used the code IvanS95 wrote down and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want it at the exact center of the screen(like from left,right,top,bottom) or just the horizontal center.

For the horizontal center, you can simply do-

```css
.parent-element{
    background: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300
}
.centered-element{
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: cyan;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-element">
  <div class="centered-element">
      Sample Text
  </div>
</div>
```